# How to evaluate these C expressions?

Tags: c

First this is the question I'm working on:

> **Evaluate each of the following expressions in C:**
>
> ```
> int x=1, y=7, z=0;  
> char a='m';
> ```
>
> **1)** `a ? y-x : x–y`
>   **2)** `x = 5 ? (y = z) : (z = y)`

I understand the rest of the questions but number **(1)** confuses me... isn't it supposed to be a logical expression? 
I mean `'m'` cannot be true nor false; how can I answer this question? Is it simply "Error"? Or is there something I missed?

For number **(2)** the statement `(z=y)` should execute which changes `z` to 7, but isn't it supposed to be `x == 5` and I tried it on a terminal and it changes both `x` and `y` to `0`.

What am I missing?

Comment: `'m'` is non-zero, ergo it evaluates to `true`.

Comment: You might want to learn about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Note that `z = y` will not be executed; `y = z` will be executed — `(test) ? if-true : if-false;` is the structure of the ternary.

Comment: Why not write a program? After all, this is a site for programming questions.

Answer (score 5):

1. In C ANY numeric type can be evaluated as a bool, and for such types, any non-zero value is 'true'.  So since the character `'m'` is non-zero (only `'\0'` is zero), it is "true"
2. Precedence -- All operators in C have precedence, and ?:, while lower than most, is higher than assignment operators.  So this expression is equivalent to:

`x = (5 ? (y = z) : (z = y))`